# Adding a maven (distribution) repository on the command line

Tags: maven, command-line, continuous-integration, repository

I think this should be possible, but I have not found anything related to it, as all I have found relates to dependency repositories.

What I would like to do is define the repository where maven (deploy, or release plugin for example) pushes the artifacts. How can I define it on the command line? I assume it is `-Dsomething`

UPDATE: When I read a jenkins error output carefully, it hints about using:
`-DaltDeploymentRepository=id::layout::url`

What Is the format for using this? What is the layout parameter?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The simplest thing is to read the [documentation about the maven-deploy-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-mojo.html) which describes the format:

```
mvn -DaltDeploymentRepository=repositoryId::default::http://WhatEverURL
```

In the distributionManagement you usually give things like:

```
 <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <id>internal.repo</id>
      <name>MyCo Internal Repository</name>
      <url>Host to Company Repository</url>
    </repository>
  </distributionManagement>
```

If you like to use a different URL in this case you need to give:

```
mvn -DaltDeploymentRepository=internal.repo::default::http://WhatEverURL
```

The *default* in this case is the default for the [maven repository layout](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Repository).

Comment: I already figured this out after I found the name of the right parameter, but Thanks!

Comment: Just a correction on the command line. According to the documentation should look like:  "mvn -daltDeploymentRepository=internal.repo::default::http://WhatEverURL"

Comment: Updated answer accordingly. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: The value `internal.repo` is a reference to the login information to use to access the repo listed as the third part of this syntax.  It was confusing to me until I learned that `internal.repo` doesn't define the URL for the repo, but instead the login information to use to access the repo specified.

Answer (score 0):

In your pom.xml you should add distributionManagement configuration to where to deploy.

In the following example I have used file system as the locations.

```
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
.........
   <distributionManagement>
       <repository>
         <id>internal.repo</id>
         <name>Internal repo</name>
         <url>file:///home/thara/testesb/in</url>
       </repository>
   </distributionManagement>
............
</project>
```

**The same thing can be done by following command:**

```
mvn deploy -DaltDeploymentRepository=internal.repo::default::file:///home/thara/testesb/in
```

Comment: How does your answer differ from @khmarbaise?